# Why use JS for Image Rollovers When I can use CSS?

Tags: javascript, css

I am making my way through Lynda.com's JS tutorial, and they have a whole chapter on image rollevers for buttons.  Why would I use JS when I could just use CSS-- to create image rollevers?

Comment: It might be because that tutorial is freaking old.

Comment: javascript provided a way to implement image rollovers before CSS existed and/or was widely adopted (we're talking circa 1998).  Now days, you should always use CSS for this sort of thing - I can't think of a single reason to favor Javascript instead.

Comment: I can find one - crossbrowser compatibility.

Comment: @easwee - Cross browser compatibility? Unless you're talking about IE 5 or less then this isn't a concern in the lease sense. The number of IE 5 users or less is monumentally small. If you're arguing that javascript rollovers should be used for cross-browser compatibility, then you're pretty much claiming that CSS is useless altogether!

Comment: @easwee I agree with @Di-0xide. You're effectively arguing against using *any* CSS when a "cross-browser" JS alternative exists.

Comment: @Di-0xide: I'm talking about IE6. Read below for reasons.

Comment: @meagar - Not any - we are talking about rollovers here right? So that means :hover browser support against onmouseover browser support for example. In this case onmouseover is a more solid rollover that will survive more browsers.

Comment: @easwee - Survive more browsers? Unless :hover is deprecated in any future browsers, there's no real reason to not use :hover. As far as I know, CSS1 was natively supported in IE6, and :hover was supported as of CSS1. Therefore, IE6 does support :hover.

Comment: @Di-0xide You don't know far enough - http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html check :hover and :active part - Ie6 - minimal support - that translates only on anchor element. Sorry but you're wrong here. If you ever build a site for ie6 you should know that.

Comment: @easwee - "that translates only on anchor element." Exactly. Unless the OP is intending for the rollover to *not* be on a link, then you're correct -- they will have a problem. However, it is supported on links, which will allow the user to create CSS rollover images for links on a page without JS. You just proved me right. :P

Answer (score 3):

> Why would I use JS when I could just use CSS-- to create image rollevers?

You shouldn't, it sounds like the tutorial may be simply using it as an example to teach you JS. There is no case where you should prefer JS to CSS when *identical results* can be achieved with CSS.

Comment: Awesome. . . at least my gut was right. . . I'm thinking this is way to much work here, when I can just use psuedo classes :-)

Comment: Note - not all psuedo classes work in every browser - js does.

Comment: @easwee - True, however for a CSS rollover all you really need is the hover psudo-class, which has been supported since CSS1, and consequently almost every browser that supports CSS.

Comment: @easwee That's specifically why I said *when **identical results** can be achieved*. Also, JS doesn't work in every browser, and while many people browse with JS turned off either explicitly or via something like NoScript, I don't think *anybody* browses with CSS turned off.

Comment: IE6 supports :hover only on <a> - at work we still have to support that so in case i need rollover on a div i have to use js. In case you don't care about old browsers than obviously use css only. The amount of users who browse without js on is less than 1% - and it's not that it doesn't work - they choose to turn it off (and they can turn off css too). But don't get me wrong - if it can be done with css - do it with css.

Answer (score 2):

At the time of those writings, the :hover pseudo class did not exist and/or was not supported by all browsers. Therefore, javascript was the preferred method of achieving the rollover effect.

Nowadays the CSS :hover pseudo class exists and is supported in all major browsers; therefore, the CSS method is preferred.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes you want to change a *content* image on rollover and not a background image (and putting two versions of a content image next to each other then using `:hover` to hide and show them puts a foot into the realm of "content not making sense without the presentation layer")

Comment: Dorward - Interesting theory. While this may not have been the reasoning behind those specific tutorials, it is definitely something to think about. Of course this would be on a per-project basis; it's up to the designer to decide which method is best suited for the site -- either content-aware or visually-aware.

Answer (score 0):

Only reason I can think (other than the ones already mentioned) is that using :hover pseudo-selector on non-anchor elements, cause performance problems in IE7 and IE8 when a strict doctype is used.

reference: http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/rendering.html#UseEfficientCSSSelectors

But in my opinion, that still isn't an enough reason to use JS over CSS.

Comment: I agree. Strict doctypes are, in my view, used for extremely basic or project-specific HTML that needs to not deviate in the least sense (like embedded HTML displays, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I think this answer [css hover vs. javascript mouseover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/608788/css-hover-vs-javascript-mouseover/3276165#3276165) of kingjeffrey is great. I would prefer this method because users with js turned off can still use the menu with most browers and users using old browsers still have a functional menu if they did not turn off js. I think this solution would make the menu usable for most cases.