# show,hide DIV with mouseover , mouseout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i want to create a simple dropdown menu with div but i have this problem:
when goes over my button div show pretty good but when mouse goes out from my link field (in this case show/hide text) my div goes to hide . how can i change my hide area button ?
because in my files i cant select links in dropdown div.

HTML code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Papermashup.com | Sliding Div</title>
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="dropdown/drop.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link type="text/css" href="dropdown/drop.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

</head>

<body>
 <a href="#" class="show_hide">Show/hide</a><br />
    <div class="slidingDiv" style="width:103px;height:60px;">
        <img alt="" height="80" src="images/dropdown.png" width="103">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS code:

```
.show_hide {
    display:none;
}
```

JavaScript code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){


    $(".slidingDiv").hide();
    $(".show_hide").show();

$('.show_hide').mouseover(function(){
    $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
});
$('.show_hide').mouseout(function(){
    $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
});

});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to wrap the link and the div into the same container,then bind the event there.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <a href="#" class="show_hide">Show/hide</a><br />
    <div class="slidingDiv" style="width:103px;height:60px;">
        <img alt="" height="80" src="images/dropdown.png" width="103">
    </div>
</div>
```

Then,rather then biding the event to show_hide, bind it to the class 'wrapper'.

Comment: can u give show me a example of this ? because when i do this my dropdown goes into crazy show hide mode

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @roacher's answer, you will also need to crop the wrapper div tightly to the image by setting a width.

You can also replace the `mouseover` / `mouseout` pairing with a [hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/608788/css-hover-vs-javascript-mouseover)

And lastly, I'm not sure you want to set the sliding div's height smaller (60px) than the image (80px)?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wR5D6/1/) here