# Submenu - Fade in and Fade out submenu in menu bar

Tags: javascript, html, css, navigation, mouseover

I want to create a menu bar in which on hover, a related extra menu should appears beside the item, and when mouse pointer goes out, it should disappears.

For example when you place your mouse pointer on your username at the top of this page, you'll see a menu contains activity, privileges, logout etc.

I want to implement such a menu.

Toggling the visibility(or changing the display) attribute of the extra menu element(such as div) is obvious.

**But my problem is** how could I detect that the mouse pointer is hovering over the extra menu, and it should NOT disappear till mouse pointer goes out!

I don't want to use JQuery.

Comment: I am feared why you don't want to use jQuery..

Comment: @VeeKayBee Because it's not needed, and also a waste to include an entire library to do something that simple Javascript can do (or even CSS3 only).

Comment: @Parrotmaster yes sure I agreed,but jQuery can help in many places like validation, ajax etc when thinking about web development. JavaScript can do everything, but jQuery gives an easy way to achieve in a less number of code.

Comment: @VeeKayBee That might be so, but the person asking the question has stated he doesn't want to use JQuery. There is also no need to ask why since any non-JQuery solution is faster and more lightweight. (for this specific question that is)

Comment: I don't compel him to use jQuery. for a curiosity I just asked why don't he ever tried jQuery. Thats all

Comment: @VeeKayBee Thanks for that. Actually I will use jQuery in my real projects later, now I want to just learn new things and ideas :)

Comment: @user1422847 its always a better practice to accept the answer which gives you a solution

Comment: @user1422847. it would be great if you could accept an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your helps and ideas.

I Think I've solved the problem:

First I've created a simple  with **fixed** width and height attributes:

```
<div id="menu" style="width:200px; height:50px; overflow:visible;">

</div>
```

Then I've added another  **INSIDE** the menu DIV !

Here I use **relative** position to use z-index attribute. (absolute position is OK too.)

The left attribute let my sub-menu appear in correct position.

The display attribute is set to none; Changing it in javascript code will display the DIV.

```
<div id="menu" style="width:200px; height:50px; overflow:visible;">
    <div id="sub-menu" style="width:200px; height:300px; position:relative; left:200px; display:none">
        ... items in sub-menu
    </div>
</div>
```

After that I've added two javascript functions for MouseOver and MouseOut :

```
<div id="menu" style="width:200px; height:50px; overflow:visible;" onmouseover="javascript: MouseOver();" onmouseout="javascript: MouseOut();">
    <div id="sub-menu" style="width:200px; height:300px; position:relative; left:200px; display:none">
        ... items in sub-menu
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
function MouseOver(){
    document.getElementById("sub-menu").style.display = "inline-block";
}

function MouseOut(){
    document.getElementById("sub-menu").style.display = "none";
}
```

In this way when mouse pointer goes over the menu DIV, the sub-menu DIV appears, and when mouse pointer goes through the sub-menu DIV, it IS STILL over the menu DIV too, so MouseOut function will not invoked !

The trick was just adding the sub-menu DIV INSIDE the main menu DIV, and use relative position for it ! changin the display attribute was obvious ;)

Excuse my bad explanation.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

## Pure CSS method

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/gvee/jrFse/

### HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>Item 1
        <ul>
            <li>Subitem 1</li>
            <li>Subitem 2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Item2</li>
    <li>Item 3
        <ul>
            <li>Subitem 1</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

### CSS

```
ul
{
    list-style-type: none;
}

ul li
{
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 3px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

ul li:hover
{
    background-color: lime;
}

li ul
{
    display: none;
}

li:hover ul
{
    display: block;
}

li ul li:hover
{
    background-color: red;
}
```

**NOTE:** There's still some styling left for you to do, this is merely to illustrate the principle.

Answer (score 1):

CSS has property

```
element:hover{}
```

For more presentable menu, use javascript

Also, if you want to change the styles of a child element on hover of parent, you may use

```
parentElement:hover childElement{}
```

So the idea could be to take a outer div(parentElement) and a label and another div(childElement) in it. On hover of the parentElement, modify the display property of childElement as shown in the above snippet.

Comment: Thanks to simple Javascript and CSS3, JQuery is no longer needed for these things. Problem with element:hover{visibility: visible;} is that you need to hover over the element itself to make it visible, which won't work properly.

Comment: Thanks for a nice simple solution. I think I've got the idea. Increasing the width of the same div is a smart solution. But I think I should use javascript to set some delay. Am I right? I'm going to test this solution now:)

Comment: @user1422847 If you want a fade effect you could use Javascript. However you could also use this: http://bavotasan.com/2011/a-simple-fade-with-css3/

Comment: the problem with the :hover selector is, that  IE till v. 7 are only accepting it for <a> tags. heres a reference http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cc848866(v=vs.85).aspx
Same counts for css transitions but here you have to use IE 10 i guess

Comment: @MaxPressburger In all honesty, you should never program with Internet Explorer in mind. It's so horribly outdated even IE10 is a joke. I personally reccomend supporting IE8 at most, and even that is stretching it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following to have a POP up menu. All you want to do it to restructure this in the way you want. You can have a demo at [here](http://jsfiddle.net/NMWB5/1/).

**HTML**

```
    <div>
 <input type="button" ID="lnkModel"  OnClick="DisplayModal();" Text="OK" />
    </div>
    <div id="overlay"></div>
    <div id="modalMsg" style="width: 200px; height: 100px; border-color: Black; border-style: solid;
        color: Red;" class="HideModal">
        This is modalpopup window
        <input type="button" ID="lnkOk"  OnClick="return RemoveModal();" Text="OK" />
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.ShowModal
 {
                top: 200px;
                left: 250px;
                z-index: 1000;
                position: absolute;
                background-color: White;
                display: block;
            }
            .HideModal
            {
                display: none;
            }
            .OverlayEffect
            {
                background-color: black;
                filter: alpha(opacity=70);
                opacity: 0.7;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                z-index: 400;
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
            }
```

**JavaScript**

```
function DisplayModal()
            {
                alert("Hai");
                document.getElementById("overlay").style.height = document.body.clientHeight + 'px';
                document.getElementById("overlay").className = "OverlayEffect";
                document.getElementById("modalMsg").className = "ShowModal";
            }
            function RemoveModal()
            {
                document.getElementById("modalMsg").className = "HideModal";        
                document.getElementById("overlay").className = "";
                return false;
            }
```

**Updates**

As per this question you can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/608788/css-hover-vs-javascript-mouseover) way to trigger the hover

```
<div onmouseover="document.getElementById('input').style.backgroundColor='Blue';">
<input id="input">
</div>
```

Check this question to know more about the difference between css and js hover events. [css hover vs. javascript mouseover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/608788/css-hover-vs-javascript-mouseover(same) question mentioned above).

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use Javascript to change the CSS property of the element that you want to make visible.

`element.style.visibility='visible'` will make your element visible, but it also reserves the space for the element, which should not be an issue since I assume the element will have a higher z-index.

For the mouse interaction, look here for the Javascript "onmouseover" event:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseover.asp

Comment: see the tags, only css

Comment: @Saksham Sorry, but you did not specify you only wanted CSS simply by only using a CSS tag. You should at least add in an HTML tag aswell, since that's what the question is related to.

Answer (score 0):

I would advice to use jQuery for this kind of stuff but here's the solution for your hover problem:

Attach your animation to the mouse events of your menu and your username.

```
 var elem =  getelementbyid("yourTrigger");
 var elem2 = getelementbyid("yourElementToShow");
 elem.onmouseover = function(e) {
        elem2.style.display = "block";
    };
    elem.onmouseout = function(e) {
        elem2.style.display = "none";
    };
    elem2.onmouseover = function(e) {
        elem2.style.display = "block";
    };
    elem2.onmouseout = function(e) {
        elem2.style.display = "none";
    };
```

Comment: see the tags, only css

Comment: the tags must have been edited - may thats why all the people write javascript solutions. 
Just saying

Comment: btw you deleted that tag and there is and was not written that it has to be done without javascript.

Comment: @Saksham Tags don't define what solutions are possible for a problem. If you don't want to use a certain technique it should always be stated in the question itself.

Comment: @Saksham so you change the task and then downvote all the answers done for the original question ? Seems not that legit.

Comment: @Saksham It's pretty obvious, since the only people with downvotes are the ones that are not you. Please refrain from forcing your opinion on others. The tags refer to the content of the question, so naturally the Javascript tag had to be removed. Javascript related answers are still very much valid and welcomed, since there is not real reason not to employ javascript (unless the person in question has specifically stated otherwise).

Comment: @Saksham Captain Obvious - who else ? :)

Comment: To be honest I need some javascript solutions too ( because of some reasons! ) I don't why it changed to CSS solutions! However ideas in CSS solutions are functional too. Thanks anyway.