# Zurb Foundation Hashtag Reveal Modal on URL Bookmark or Backlinking

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, zurb-foundation-5

I'm using ZURB Foundation 5 along with their JS Script 'Reveal Modal'. What I'd like to do is be able to have the modal display upon URL hashtag within the URL.

*The Trigger*

```
<a href="#bits-n-bobs" data-reveal-id="bits-n-bobs">Bits and Bobs</a></li>
```

*The Reveal Modal*

```
<div id="bits-n-bobs" class="reveal-modal" data-reveal>
    <h2>Bits and Bobs</h2>
    <p>Basil fawlty ron burgundy kris kristofferson.</p>
    <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
</div>
```

While the hashtag is not required in the a href the reasoning behind this is so when `.no-js` is being used the `display:none` becomes `display:block` meaning that the links least do something when no java-script is detected.

*Solution I Need*

Now because I'm using hash-tags within a `<a href>` the URL updates when revealing a modal box, while this isn't a problem I would like a solution that if someone book marks, or shares a's a link with the hashtag the box auto revealings itself.

For example if I clicked ***Bits and Bobs*** the url would be `sitename.com/#bits-n-bobs` and it'd reveal the modal. What I want is when someone links the domain with the hashtag upon visiting that page with the hashtag it opens the Reveal Modal using JavaScript ***without the need to Click***.

I imagine this is something rather easy to do with JavaScript but its one of my weakest areas and appreciate any help or least pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Look into on hover in JavaScript: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/608788/css-hover-vs-javascript-mouseover

Comment: Thanks but that page has nothing to do with Hashtag and Modal boxes. It's about Hover overs. I want a Modal that triggers via JavaScript and by Hashtag URL access.

Answer (score 1):

On load you can get the `id` from the URL with `window.location.hash` and then trigger the modal with this `$('#myModal').foundation('reveal', 'open');` [[source]](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/reveal.html).

Also check if an element exists with that `id` and has a class `reveal-modal` before opening it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var target = $(window.location.hash);
   if(target.length > 0 && target.hasClass('reveal-modal'))  {
     target.foundation('reveal', 'open');
   }
});
```