# HTML/CSS - Using "dynamic margins" (variables(?) - How do I?

Tags: html, css, margins

I've been looking through the code of some websites, and notice that the margin sizes change depending on certain actions (eg, mouse hover, screen width) to create a cool dynamic effect.
This effect can be seen here when changing screen width:
http://www.smashbros.com/us/

And here on mouse hover:
http://www.disneyanimation.com/projects

I really have no clue how this is done!
How can the code values automatically change based on certain actions.

Thanks in advance

edit:

I tried something.... but it isn't really giving me the results I want

```
.cats {
background-color: #eee;
height: 90px;
width: 100%;
}

.cats {
-webkit-animation-duration: 0.5s;
-webkit-animation-name: slide-up;
-moz-animation-duration: 0.5s;
-moz-animation-name: slide-up;
}

.cats {
-webkit-animation: slide-up 0.5s linear;
-moz-animation: slide-up 0.5s linear;
-webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
-moz-animation-play-state: paused;
}

.cats :hover {
  /* Toggle the animation play state to running when we are hovering over our sticker */
-webkit-animation-play-state: running;
-moz-animation-play-state: running;
}

@-webkit-keyframes slide-up {
from {
    margin-top: 0px
}
to {
    margin-top: -15px
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to make a start yourself; but first try to find some tutorials on how to start with HTML and CSS. Then, once you've made a start, and have begin to understand the syntax of selectors, and pseudo-classes, it begins to make sense. And becomes understandable, and strangely compelling and addictive.

Comment: thanks!
I've been coding for sometime but never really explored animation.
I tried something in my edit....am I on the right track? haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To move gradually, you can apply **transition** to your div. For example **transition: 0.6s;**

For more info on transitions property please visit [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp).

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this using CSS the hover selector as per @David's answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/905042/3264286

Further details here:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp

Alternatively, if you are happy to use JavaScript, you can have a lot more power.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseover.asp

More discussion:

[css hover vs. javascript mouseover](https://stackoverflow.com/q/608788/3264286)

Comment: Thanks that helps!
however, my questions was more directed at achieving the "moving effect".
For example:

div:hover {
    margin-top: -20px;
}

This will move the div up by twenty px immediately
what I want is for it to move gradually

Comment: Have a look at the JavaScript / jQuery code in this forum, it'll work just as you want: [https://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-animate-hover-function](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-animate-hover-function)

Comment: @ArmanHaque:To move gradually, you can apply transition to your div. For example transition: 0.6s;

Comment: @ArmanHaque : You are welcome :) Should I post it as an answer?

Comment: @ArshadMuhammed Please do.
Jazakallah

Comment: @ArmanHaque:Jazakallah