# change multiple div background color when on hover using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 4 blue div boxes in a tile like structure. I would like to change the color of the other 3 when the mouse hovers over the just one of boxes using jquery. This block of code does not seem to do the job. any help would be much appreciated!

```
<div class="box" style=" height: 150px; width: 150px; border:5px solid black"></div>
<div class="box" style="height: 150px; width: 150px; border:5px solid black"></div>
<div class="box" style="height: 150px; width: 150px; border:5px solid black"></div>
<div class="box" style="height: 150px; width: 150px; border:5px solid black"></div>

$(document).ready((function () {
    $(".box1").mouseover(function () {
        $(".box2").css("background-color", "red");
        $(".box3").css("background-color", "green");
        $(".box4").css("background-color", "orange");
    });
});
```

Comment: You have a couple of typos in your jQuery. Check your console for the errors. Working example http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/xk3ke75e/

Comment: Please post relevant HTML also

Comment: how are you planning to assign colors to each remaining boxes, same colour, or random different colors ? and also, whther u want hover on only one box i.e box1

Comment: Your code is correct, you have one typo just after ready method opens. You have 2 brackets there.

Comment: @j08691 Nicely done, I have the feeling that the op  may have also desired to have this effect reversed on mouseout, so i have an updated fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/nvrtfsod/

Comment: @Nielarshi When the user moves the mouse over a box, the color  changes to yellow, while the color of the other three boxes changes to red, green and orange.

Comment: HTML code posted after this comment @phillip100

Comment: @D00ble : I have added my answer. have a look if it solves ur purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use single `.box` class on each div, set color in `data` attribute of each div and grab it on `hover`

HTML:

```
<div data-color="grey" class="box"></div>
<div data-color="red" class="box"></div>
<div data-color="green" class="box"></div>
<div data-color="orange" class="box"></div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".box").hover(function () {
        // change hovered div background to yellow:
        $(this).css("background-color", 'yellow');
        // loop through the rest of the divs with the same class:
        $(".box").not(this).each(function(){
            // change their background color according to their 'data-color' attribute:
            $(this).css("background-color", $(this).data('color'));
        });
       // set hover out method:
    }, function(){
        // change each 'box' background color to default:
        $(".box").css("background-color", '');
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/2paaujmo/)

---

Or, if you need **only** these 3 colors (*red*, *green* and *orange*) to be applied to the other boxes, you could use something like this:

```
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

```
$(".box").hover(function () {
    $(this).css("background-color", 'yellow');
    $(".box").not(this).each(function(i){
        $(this).css("background-color", (['red','green','orange'])[i]);
    });
}, function(){
    $(".box").css("background-color", '');
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/s05rcft0/)

Comment: I appreciate your help, i tried both ways but there is no change in the color of any of the div boxes. my html for each div box looks like this-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------<div class="box" style="height: 150px; width: 150px; border:5px solid black"></div>

Comment: @D00ble , Have you included jQuery library in the page? It does work [**Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/L6ypfdpm/)

Comment: yes i have it linked to my html page copied and pasted your code exactly as is, saved and refreshed the browser.... no effect

Comment: @D00ble , then the problem is somewhere else. Difficult to say where it could be without seeing the rest of the code and HTML.

Comment: You have included this what I already know :) . As I wrote in previous comment - the code **shold** work with what you have posted (see [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/L6ypfdpm/), it's exactly the same as your HTML). The problem is somewhere else.

Comment: i see yours works just fine. for some reason mine does not. Unfortunately i cannot upload a screenshot since i have a low reputation. Thanks for your help. ill keep trying to figure it out

Comment: finally got it. I didn't link my jquery library first in my header tag. Apparently it has to be the first linked file. once again i appreciate all your help!

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with **CSS General Sibling Selector `~`** too. Here is an example :

```css
.box {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    border: 1px solid;
}
.box1:hover ~ .box2 {
    background: red;
}
.box1:hover ~ .box3 {
    background: green;
}
.box1:hover ~ .box4 {
    background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="box box1">Box 1</div>
<div class="box box2">Box 2</div>
<div class="box box3">Box 3</div>
<div class="box box4">Box 4</div>
```

Comment: but i would like to get it done using jquery and not css

Comment: Ok. This is just an alternate way to do it. It seems that you have already got answers with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".box1").mouseover(function () {
        $(".box2").css("background-color", "red");
        $(".box3").css("background-color", "green");
        $(".box4").css("background-color", "orange");
    });
});
```

Comment: Please explain what you did.

Comment: $(document).ready((function (){ instead of this i put $(document).ready(function (){

Answer (score 0):

i did this fast for you, hope it is what you need [CodePen](http://codepen.io/ZetCoby/pen/MYqymJ)

```
$(".box").hover(function () {
            $(".box").css("background", "red");
            $(".box1").css("background", "green");
    },function(){
            $(".box, .box1").css("background", "#262626");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Also try this: you can use `.hover` and remove the double braces in `ready((function () {`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".box1").hover(function () {
        $(".box2").css("background-color", "red");
        $(".box3").css("background-color", "green");
        $(".box4").css("background-color", "orange");
    });
});
```

Further info, related **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/608788/css-hover-vs-javascript-mouseover)**.

Answer (score 0):

I have created this piece of code which I guess will help you,

HTML

```
<div class="box box1" id="box1"></div>
<div class="box box2" id="box2"></div>
<div class="box box3" id="box3"></div>
<div class="box box4" id="box4"></div>
```

CSS

```
.box {
  width : 100px;
  height : 100px;
  border : 1px solid gray;
}
.yellow {
  background : yellow;
}
.red {
  background : red;
}
.green {
  background : green;
}
.orange {
  background : orange;
}
```

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var colorArray = ['red', 'green', 'orange'];

    function assignRandomBackgroundToElement(element, color) {
         element.addClass(color);
    }

    function assignRandomBackgroundToRemainingElements(remainingBoxIndexes, elementArray) {
      remainingBoxIndexes.forEach(function(ele, index) {
         assignRandomBackgroundToElement($(elementArray[ele]), colorArray[index]);
      });
    }
    $(".box").mouseover(function () {
        var element = $(this);
        element.addClass('yellow');
        var totalBoxes = $(".box").length;
        var currentIndex = 0;
        var remainingBoxIndexes = [];
        $(".box").each(function(index, ele){
          if($(ele).attr('id')===element.attr('id')) {
            currentIndex = index;
          } else {
            remainingBoxIndexes.push(index);
          }
        });
        assignRandomBackgroundToRemainingElements(remainingBoxIndexes, $(".box"));

    });

  $(".box").mouseout(function () {
        $(".box").removeClass('red green orange yellow');     
  });
});
```