# Should :hover and the mouseout event have the same "firing" causes?

Tags: html, css

When I programmed an aspx site I run into the problem that a div that had a couple of elements and was displayed on top of other elements (due to position: fixed) went invisible despite my wishes to the contrary.

This div was to be invisible if the mouse left the area it contained. As easy as it seemed thoughtwise I used:

```
<div id="xyz" onmouseout="JavaScript: $('#xyz').hide();">....</div>
```

this triggered when I left the padding area that was defined for the div and entered the elements, or the space between elements (elements inside the div),.... .

Now when instead I used css to perform the hide:

```
#xyz.HideOnNotHovered { display: none; }
#xyz.HideOnNotHovered:hover { display: inline-block; }
```

That worked as intended. Thus Regardles where my mousepointer was inside the div it was visible, only when it left the div did the div disappear.

This situation (which I could not recreated in jsfiddle thanks to a complex layer of css and javascripts involved which I couldn't put in there) birthed a question:

When I first thought about the problem I had thought that onmouseout event and the ending routines of :hover are essentially the same (or that onmouseover and :hover are the same and that onmouseout is called only under the circumstances when :hover ends and only under the same circumstances). So the question I have is: Is/Should there any difference between onmouseout and the opposite of :hover?

Comment: I think these answers, answer your question aswell  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/608788/css-hover-vs-javascript-mouseover

Comment: Have you set DOCTYPE for your document?

Comment: @LinkinTED The answers there are quite interesting but didn't see any direct answer to my question there. From what I read there the answers have the same thought as I had that: mouseover + mouseout = :hover in essence (which I have observed above isn't always the case as mouseout triggers for me at different times than when :hover ends).

Comment: @AliSheikhpour Yes. <!DOCTYPE html> is at the beginning of the html document (just doublechecked)

Answer (score 3):

This is the same difference between jQuery `mouseout` and `mouseleave` events :

- `mouseleave` is triggered only when the cursor leave the targeted element - [exemple](https://jsfiddle.net/hs9fgdm5/)
- `mouseout` is triggered everytime the cursor leave the targeted element **AND** is hover a child element - [exemple](https://jsfiddle.net/gq09qmdg/)

---

This is the same behaviour for `:hover` (css) and `onmouseout` in javascript :

- `:hover` is applied while the cursor is within the targeted element - [exemple](https://jsfiddle.net/7m9aozar/)
- `onmouseout` is triggered everytime the cursor leave the targeted element **AND** is hover a child element - [exemple](https://jsfiddle.net/82cd3c5k/)

---

> [Here's a good referal](http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/different-between-mouseout-and-mouseleave-in-jquery/) on this two different behaviours