# Enlarge photo in a cell without moving other elements with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, hover, photo

So I've got a few tables next to each other.

In first row, there's a picture and then in next few rows some text. I need to use JavaScript to make the photo expand to all rows on hover ( fill the table ) without moving other elements . How can I do this?

Comment: It sounds like `flex` or `css-grids` would serve you better.

Comment: Would you consider a image modal popup when user clicks on modal instead?

Comment: I must use Javascript

Comment: Not sure where you are with this.  How are images sized in your table now?  (hint, sure would be nice to see code, including key CSS settings...)  Also, [this posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/608788/css-hover-vs-javascript-mouseover) may help a bit...  What class are you taking?