# How to get different DOM elements with different suffix number? Shorthand way?

Tags: javascript

I was wondering if there's a easier way to get this working without declaring each one of the elements, one by one...

My intention is to change the opacity of certain divs when hovering over li elements

```
const exp1 = document.getElementById('itemContent1');
const exp2 = document.getElementById('itemContent2');
const exp3 = document.getElementById('itemContent3');
const exp4 = document.getElementById('itemContent4');
const exp5 = document.getElementById('itemContent5');
const desc1 = document.getElementById('expDesc1');
const desc2 = document.getElementById('expDesc2');
const desc3 = document.getElementById('expDesc3');
const desc4 = document.getElementById('expDesc4');
const desc5 = document.getElementById('expDesc5');


exp1.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
    desc1.style.opacity = '1'
})

exp1.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
    desc1.style.opacity = '0'
})

exp2.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
    desc1.style.opacity = '1'
})

exp2.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
    desc1.style.opacity = '0'
})

exp3.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
    desc1.style.opacity = '1'
})

exp3.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
    desc1.style.opacity = '0'
})

exp4.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
    desc1.style.opacity = '1'
})

exp4.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
    desc1.style.opacity = '0'
})

exp5.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
    desc1.style.opacity = '1'
})

exp5.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
    desc1.style.opacity = '0'
})
```

HTML:

```
<section class="about">
    <div class="timeline">
        <ul class="mainList">
            <li><p id="itemContent1">experiencia 1</p><div id="expDesc1">description</div></li>
            <li><p id="itemContent2">experiencia 2</p><div id="expDesc2">description</div></li>
            <li><p id="itemContent3">experiencia 3</p><div id="expDesc3">description</div></li>
            <li><p id="itemContent4">experiencia 4</p><div id="expDesc4">description</div></li>
            <li><p id="itemContent5">experiencia 5</p><div id="expDesc5">description</div></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</section>
```

I'm new to this, sorry if this is too dumb... I couldn't find the answer on Google or here.

Comment: You could probably use DOM traversal to relate the `itemContentN` elements to the `expDescN` elements, however we'd need to see your HTML to confirm that. Best case scenario would be to use CSS to do this, not JS.

Comment: document.querySelectorAll('[id^="itemContent"') to select all elements with an id starting with itemContent. But you will still need to loop on them to add your listeners. Edited to querySelectorAll as per @ControlAltDel comment

Comment: You can use CSS for this

Comment: @user3252327 you mean querySelectorAll

Comment: yes indeed I meant document.querySelectorAll('[id^="itemContent"')

Comment: based on @RoryMcCrossan comment, you can create a `class` just for opacity control. here is a question with similar subject that might help ---- > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/608788/css-hover-vs-javascript-mouseover#:~:text=There%20is%20another%20difference%20to,the%20rest%20of%20the%20page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they are in sorted order, you can use `querySelectorAll` to get all the elements which id start with `itemContent` and `expDesc` and loop through to `itemContent` and add events and change the opacity to the corresponding index to `expDesc`

```js
const exps = document.querySelectorAll('[id^="itemContent"]');

const descs = document.querySelectorAll('[id^="expDesc"]');

exps.forEach((exp, i) => {
  exp.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
    descs[i].style.opacity = '1'
  })

  exp.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
    descs[i].style.opacity = '0'
  })
})
```

```css
.hide {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<section class="about">
    <div class="timeline">
        <ul class="mainList">
            <li><p id="itemContent1">experiencia 1</p><div class="hide" id="expDesc1">description</div></li>
            <li><p id="itemContent2">experiencia 2</p><div class="hide" id="expDesc2">description</div></li>
            <li><p id="itemContent3">experiencia 3</p><div class="hide" id="expDesc3">description</div></li>
            <li><p id="itemContent4">experiencia 4</p><div class="hide" id="expDesc4">description</div></li>
            <li><p id="itemContent5">experiencia 5</p><div class="hide" id="expDesc5">description</div></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

CSS only

```css
.mainList li div { 
  opacity: 0
}

.mainList li p:hover + div { 
  opacity: 1
}
```

```html
<section class="about">
  <div class="timeline">
    <ul class="mainList">
      <li>
        <p id="itemContent1">experiencia 1</p>
        <div id="expDesc1">description</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p id="itemContent2">experiencia 2</p>
        <div id="expDesc2">description</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p id="itemContent3">experiencia 3</p>
        <div id="expDesc3">description</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p id="itemContent4">experiencia 4</p>
        <div id="expDesc4">description</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p id="itemContent5">experiencia 5</p>
        <div id="expDesc5">description</div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>
```

As always I recommend delegation if you MUST use JS:

Now we COULD use nextElementSibling, but this is more flexible

```js
const overandout = e => {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.matches("p")) e.target.closest("li").querySelector("div").style.opacity = e.type === "mouseover" ? 1 : 0;
};
const list = document.querySelector(".mainList");
list.addEventListener("mouseover", overandout)
list.addEventListener("mouseout", overandout)
```

```css
.mainList li div {
  opacity: 0
}
```

```html
<section class="about">
  <div class="timeline">
    <ul class="mainList">
      <li>
        <p id="itemContent1">experiencia 1</p>
        <div id="expDesc1">description</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p id="itemContent2">experiencia 2</p>
        <div id="expDesc2">description</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p id="itemContent3">experiencia 3</p>
        <div id="expDesc3">description</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p id="itemContent4">experiencia 4</p>
        <div id="expDesc4">description</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p id="itemContent5">experiencia 5</p>
        <div id="expDesc5">description</div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>
```